# ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9090 in Jenkins in a newman report

Tags: jenkins, newman, postman-collection-runner

I'm running a pipeline with a newman command in jenkins, the tests give me OK, but it's the first time I get that error, in other newman reports it never came out, I don't understand why this error. Some help? I attach an image of the error.[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you have proxy enabled, disable it or configure `newman` for [proxy](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-request/blob/master/README.md#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables)